# What is the significance of 'text/html' in getData("text/html")?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across the following code

```
clipboardData.getData('text/html');
```

I know that the getData method is fetching the data from clipboardData object what I don't know is the use of **'text/html'** I have also seen more examples such as **'text/url'**. Can you specify what **other strings** are **accepted** instead of text/html or text/url and their significance. Please help I am new to JS.

Comment: It is for which format the data read from clipboard has. It can be an image as well and so on. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData

Comment: it could be anything. it will accept string only